# 'ProjectName-Swift.h' file not found on Xcode 9 using Swift 4?

Tags: objective-c, swift, swift3, ios11, swift4

I am trying to add **swift 4** file in objective c project on Xcode 9. For that i am following these steps -

step 1: suppose swift class name is  ShowAlertSwift.swift

```
   import UIKit

    @objc public class ShowAlertSwift: NSObject {

    @objc func printSome() {
        print("Print line System")
    }
    @objc func test () {
        print("Test swift Class in objective C project")
    }
}
```

step 2 : And the objective -c class first declare  @class ShowAlertSwift

In objectiveClass.h I have followed these step

```
@class ShowAlertSwift

@interface ShowAlertSwift: NSObject

-(void)test;
-(void)printSome;

@end

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

step 3 - In objectiveClass.m

```
#import "myproject-swift.h"

@interface UIViewController ()
{

}

@implementation
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     ShowAlertSwift *alertObj = [[ShowAlertSwift alloc]init];
     [alertObj test];
}
```

I also set the following properties

```
Defines modules - Yes
Embedded_Content_Contains_Swift - Yes
Install Objective-C compatibility header - Yes
Objective C bridging header - $(SRCROOT)/Sources/SwiftBridging.h
Product Module Name - projectName
```

After all these stuff I am getting errors like

```
1. myproject-swift.h file not found
2. Consecutive statement on a line must be seprated by ';'
3. failed to emit precompiled header '/Users/xyz/pqr/Trunk/build/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/myproject-Bridging-Header-swift_1CBSOZ0HA1Z9R-clang_UESSBOJR5CSH.pch' for bridging header '/Users/xyz/pqr/Trunk/OpenPage2/com/myProject/login/Login_iPad/myProject-Bridging-Header.h'
```

Can any one has any idea how to resolve the issue on Xcode 9 in Swift 4 ?

Comment: `#import "myproject-Swift.h"`, where the word _Swift_ prefixes capitol `S` ([source](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html))

Answer (score 5):

I have done lots of thing to resolve this issue but I was not getting success. But Due to my dedication finally i solved this issue -

> Note : To access swift class in objective C code you have to use the
>   @objec keyword along the class statement like that

```
 @objc public class ShowAlertSwift: NSObject
```

First create an swift class

```
 import UIKit

    @objc public class ShowAlertSwift: NSObject {

    @objc func printSome() {
        print("Print line System")
    }
    @objc func test () {
        print("Test swift Class in objective C project")
    }
}
```

In objectiveClass.h I have followed these step

```
    @class ShowAlertSwift

    @interface ViewController : UIViewController

    @end
```

here there is no need to define an interface again as this interface is already exist in "myproject-swift.h" file. Refer question First to understand clearly or see below

```
@interface ShowAlertSwift: NSObject

-(void)test;
-(void)printSome;

@end
```

step 3 - In objectiveClass.m

```
#import "myproject-swift.h"

@interface UIViewController ()
{

}

@implementation
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     ShowAlertSwift *alertObj = [[ShowAlertSwift alloc]init];
     [alertObj test];
}
```

Also enable/update these properties in your build settings -

```
1. Defines Module set to YES (Mandatory on project - not on target)

2. Embedded_Content_Contains_Swift - Yes
3. Install Objective-C compatibility header - Yes
4. Objective C bridging header - $(SRCROOT)/Sources/SwiftBridging.h
5. Product Module Name - projectName
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you delete derived data ? if not then delete derived data and then clean+build your app .

This was help me in my code . So hope you will not get error.

Comment: I have deleted the derived data , clean and build but still getting the same errors which i mentioned above.

1. myproject-swift.h file not found
2. Consecutive statement on a line must be seprated by ';'

Comment: Go to header search path and delete all the code from there after that add new by pressing + icon and from xcode drag and drop the path of your ProjectName-Bridging-Header and try

Answer (score 0):

I renamed the base folder of the project and that's why the problem is occurred.

So I had to rename each error line like

Restaurant-swift.h to FoodPicker_Restaurant-swift.h

the "-" is for the Space at the project name.